# Xcode iOS constraints linked to variables

Tags: ios, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I was wondering whether it was possible to set constraints which reference a variable and adjust dynamically according to an integer or float value?

Thanks 
D

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should declare outlet

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *view1TopConstraint;
```

Then you should link this outlet in interface builder like you link any other outlets.

Finally, in your code where it is necessary, do:

```
view1TopConstraint.constant = 50.f;
```

Of course everything depends on complexity of your logic, somewhere this approach is simpler, but in big things you'd better to use VFL. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html